# How to hide a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I want to do something simple, to hide an entire TableView, something like:

```
self.tableView.visible=false
```

It is strange, but all I have found on is info on how to hide just cells/empty cells inside the table.
How can I hide the ENTIRE table???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A table view is also a view. Every view has a `hidden` property, so set `self.tableView.hidden = true`. There is no `visible` property.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `hidden` property of `UITableView`.

```
self.tableView.hidden = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this: `self.tableView.hidden = true`.